Why does the touch event only work sometimes?
I would like to make a touch event that works like a click on a button to toggle an expander. The problem is related to this component.
The problem is that on one component and DOM it works fine and on another it doesn't.
    <div class={`title-card-header${config['title-card-button-overlay'] ? '-overlay' : ''}`}>
        <div class="title-card-container" style="--title-padding:{config['title-card-padding']}" on:touchstart|passive={touchStart} on:touchmove|passive={touchMove} on:touchend={touchEnd}>
            <Card {hass} config={config['title-card']} type={config['title-card'].type} />
        </div>


let touchElement: HTMLElement | undefined;
let isScrolling = false;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;
const touchStart = (event: TouchEvent) => {
    touchElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
    startX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    isScrolling = false;
};

const touchMove = (event: TouchEvent) => {
    const currentX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    const currentY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    if (Math.abs(currentX - startX) > 10 || Math.abs(currentY - startY) > 10) {
        isScrolling = true;
    }
};

const touchEnd = (event: TouchEvent) => {
    if (!isScrolling && touchElement === event.target && config['title-card-clickable']) {
        open = !open;
    }
    touchElement = undefined;
};

This DOM works fine and without any issue
<div class="title-card-header-overlay">
  <div class="title-card-container">
    <div style="margin-top: 0px;">
      <mushroom-template-card dark-mode=""></mushroom-template-card>
    </div> 
   </div> 
</div> 

It doesn't work with this one. You can see that the status changes briefly. However, immediately afterwards it resets again, so that it flickers.
<div class="title-card-header-overlay">
  <div class="title-card-container">
    <div style="margin-top: 0px;">
      <digital-clock-card></digital-clock-card>
    </div> 
   </div> 
</div>

Both element contains all 3 touch listener on title-card-container
Now my question is, does anyone have experience with this and can tell me what I could check? What could be wrong?
And is there a good simulator to perhaps simulate touch events on the desktop?
EDIT:
I found out a difference, in one case the click listener is still executed and in the other case it is not.

For simulating touch events: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode#type

Thanks I will try that..
EDIT: Works fine I can reproduce the issue. Maybe i can add some console logs
